# How to use the function keys in Excel on a Mac?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I have just transferred from Microsoft to Mac.
On my MacBook Pro I cannot use the <kbd>F#</kbd> keys in Excel.  I used to use <kbd>F4</kbd> to repeat the last action and <kbd>F9</kbd>to recalculate.

I have found that <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> does the repeat, e.g. replaces <kbd>F4</kbd>.

How can I replicate the <kbd>F9</kbd> in Excel on a Mac?

What key combination do I need to press?

Comment: [226 Shortcuts for Microsoft Excel 2016 (MacOS)](https://shortcutworld.com/Excel/mac/Microsoft-Excel_2016_Shortcuts)

Answer (score 1):

From [this overview of 226 shortcuts for Excel 2016 on a Mac](https://shortcutworld.com/Excel/mac/Microsoft-Excel_2016_Shortcuts) I find that to replicate <kbd>F9</kbd>
you need to press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> to calculate all open workbooks.

Alternatively if you have a keyboard with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, you can press  <kbd>Fn</kbd> + the key that is associated with  <kbd>F9</kbd> (play or something).